# Fetching nvarchar column with Japanese text from Microsoft SQL Server 2016 in R returns “????”

Tags: r, sql-server

Fetching `nvarchar` column with Japanese text from Microsoft SQL Server 2016 in R returns “????”.

Event tried to pass encoding = "UTF-8" in dbconnect but no luck.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks

```
  require(odbc)

 # This function takes a string vector and turns it into a list of raw UTF-16LE bytes. 
 # These will be needed to load into SQL Server
  convertToUTF16 <- function(s){
  lapply(s, function(x) unlist(iconv(x,from="UTF-8",to="UTF- 
  16LE",toRaw=TRUE)))
  }



 # our example data
  inputData <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), Char = c("My", "ウェブサイトはダウンしている、もしくはフリーズしています。" ,"Data"))
  inputData
  # we adjust the column with the UTF-8 strings to instead 
  # be a list column of UTF-16LE bytes
  inputData$Char <- convertToUTF16(inputData$Char)
  inputData

 #creat a connection to a sql table

  con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
             Driver = "SQL Server",
             Server = "MSSQL20161",
             Database = "MYSCHEMA",
             UID = "USER",
             PWD = "PASSWORD")

 # mention field.types as nvarchar and create/write the table to the database 
 dbWriteTable(conn = con,
         name = "Example",
         value = inputData,
         append=T,
         field.types = c(Char = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")
 )

 #reading data from mssql table again
 readquery="SELECT * FROM Example"
 outputdata=sqldf(readquery,conn = con)
 outputdata

   ID                          Char
1  1                            My
2  2 ?????????????????????????????
3  3                          Data
```

For completeness, here's my sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
Matrix products: default
locale:
LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252
LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252 
LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
LC_NUMERIC=C 
LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] odbc_1.1.6    sqldf_0.4-11  RSQLite_2.1.1 gsubfn_0.7    proto_1.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.17    digest_0.6.15   chron_2.3-52    DBI_1.0.0       rlang_0.2.1     blob_1.1.1      tools_3.5.0     bit64_0.9-7    
[9] bit_1.1-14      hms_0.4.2       compiler_3.5.0  pkgconfig_2.0.1 tcltk_3.5.0     memoise_1.1.0
```

Comment: Can you provide a round-trip test? That is, create a proper string (that has correct Japanese characters) in R, write to SQL Server, and then query it back and show the problem remains.

Comment: Manually create the table in SQL Server first, making sure to create an NVARCHAR column
Change the column in R from being a string column to a list column of UTF-"16LE raw bytes."  : https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues/215

Comment: @MitchWheat : Yes i used the same suggestion to write Japanese data from R to MSSQL db and it worked very well. But now when i am reading back same data from MSSQL using R then getting data as '????'

Comment: @r2evans : Modified question with  complete example of first pushing Japanese charters from R to mssql db and then reading again from DB using R

Comment: Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Able to fix problem by changing data type to NVARCHAR(4000) from NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks